# How would I display two times with different timezones in the taskbar?

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

Is there any way to display a normal time in the taskbar along with a UTC time next to it? Other answers to similar questions show you how to do this by hovering over the time, but not any way to have it always visible, also they are from years ago, and might not be compatible with windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

I found this app https://github.com/marticliment/ElevenClock?tab=readme-ov-file which allowed me to do it, but you have to go into settings, set it to use internet time instead of your local computer's time, and enable "Set a custom network time provider", then use a worldtimeapi link that you want, in my case "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/GMT-0". This displays the clock in the bottom right, which would cover the default clock normally, but if you set your taskbar to be vertical, then they are basically right on top of each other. Here is how the two clocks on top of each other look:

[image]